# Run cucumber tests through remote selenium grid

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, cucumber, automated-tests, selenium-grid

I've set up some cucumber tests for my angular app which works fine if I run it with selenium server locally.

Now I want to run the tests through a remote selenium grid (preparation to put everything on Jenkins). That doesn't go as smoothly as I hoped though. I get the following error:

```
Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "angular could not be found on the window"
```

I was hoping someone could give me some insight on this? Here's my conf file is that's of any help (I've masked the selenium grid address...). When I run it locally I uncomment the chromedriver and seleniumserverjar parts and comment the seleniumaddress part.

```
exports.config = {
    //chromeDriver: '../../node_modules/selenium-chromedriver/bin/chromedriver.exe',

    //seleniumServerJar: '../../node_modules/selenium-server-standalone-jar/jar/selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar',


    seleniumAddress: 'http://x.x.x.x:4444/wd/hub',

    framework: 'cucumber',
    specs: [
        'features/*.feature'
    ],
    rootElement: "[ng-app]",
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {
            args: ['--disable-gpu']
        },
        version: '',
        platform: 'ANY'
    },
    cucumberOpts: {
        require: ['step_definitions/*_steps.js'],
        format: 'pretty'
    }
};
```

I fire my cucumber tests from gulpfile. The task configuration is as follows:

```
gulp.task('cucumber', ['js', 'connect:st', 'clean:e2eReporters'], function () {
return gulp.src([])
    .pipe($.protractor.protractor({
        configFile: './test/system-test/cucumber.conf.js',
        args: ['--baseUrl', 'http://' + ip.address() + ':9001']
    }))
    .on('error', function (err) {
        $.connect.serverClose();
        throw err;
    }).once('end', function (err) {
        process.exit();
    });
});
```

Comment: You have to specify default url for the tests i.e. machine hosting the application. if your machine is `x.y.z.a` then `baseUrl: http://x.y.z.a/app`

Comment: Thanks for your answer maurycy. I'm passing the baseUrl from my gulp task runner. I've expanded my post to show it.

Comment: You should check it from other machine, if you can open the URL and see your application. It is possible some resources aren't loaded causing issues